# Calculate autocorrelation function for autoregressive model in python

Tags: python, regression, arima, autocorrelation

I am looking for a python solution how to get ACF of AR process.

Expect there is autoregressive process AR(p) of order *p* which defines the following timeseries.

[formula](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?&space;X_t=%5Csum_%7Bi%7D%5E%7Bp%7D%5Cphi_iX_%7Bt-i%7D+%5Cepsilon_t,)

where [formula](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?&space;%5Cphi_i) are the coefficients of the model.

Further expect I know particular set of the coefficients. And I would like to know to autocorrelation function ACF(t) of the timeseries given by AR(p) model.

[formula](https://latex.codecogs.com/svg.image?ACF(t)=%5Csum_%7Bn=-%5Cinfty%7D%5E%7B%5Cinfty%7DX(n)X(n-t))

Is there a way how to get ACF directly from AR coefficients?

I have tried to employ statsmodels modul to get the solution. Particularly the function [statsmodels.tsa.arima_process.arma_acf](https://www.statsmodels.org/dev/generated/statsmodels.tsa.arima_process.arma_acf.html). However it is supposed to work with ARMA model and supplying MA as empty array raised an exception.